# How would you make a horizontal bar graph from an array in MIPS

Tags: arrays, mips, bar-chart

I have actually no idea how to go about this, and when I search this nothing comes up, it looks like this is an uncommon assignment to get? I have to make an array of n  non-negative integers and then print a horizontal bar graph. Then print 0-20 stars for each value, and print the value.

So i'm guessing the array is of a length I want, and the contents in the array will dictate the bar length height, so an array containing 4, 5, 6, 7 would be that tall in height in the bar respectively. What I want to know is how in the world am I making a bar graph. would it just be printing a whole bunch of these | stacked on each other for the amount in the current index?

I can't even guess how to put a star in there, does MIPS take text symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the array like `{ 2, 6, ...,3}` then you'd have output like:

```
2 * *
6 * * * * * *
...
3 * * *
```

As far as printing characters in MIPS, check:
[mips printing characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011579/mips-printing-characters)