# How to save a char in a register in mips?

Tags: mips

I'm working on a tic tac toe implementation code in MIPS and need to save the char 'x' in a $s0 register but MARS won't let me do it. I'm aware of how to save an integer value

addi $s0, $zero, 1
#at least that's how i've been teached to do it

However I need to do that exact assignation with a char, in this case 'x' or '1'.

It can be more understandable this way.

In a normal coding language it would be something like this:

char variable='x'

How can I do this in MIPS? Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mips printing characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011579/mips-printing-characters)

Comment: The ASCII code of a character is just an integer, so `addi $s0, $zero, 'x'` should work just fine. (or `li $s0, 'x'` if your assembler supports the `li` pseudo-instruction).